# Default Enumeration Methods

Tags: java, enums

An enum contains the name and `valueOf` methods.

Agian we know that the Java Compiler automatically generates a static method for each enum, called values.

This method returns an array of all constants defined inside the enum.

As there is an **static method values**, then why should we use `name()` method? Then what are the difference between the static method `values()` and the `valueof()` method?

Comment: Eh, `.valueOf()` and `.values()` don't serve the same purpose at all...

Comment: Read their javadoc, and you'll see what they're for. `name()` is an instance method which returns the name of the instance. `valueOf()` is a static method taking a String and returning the enum instance with that name. `values()` is a static method returning all the enum instances.

Comment: @JBNizet Why not post your comment as an answer? I think it's about as good as OP can hope for.

Comment: @Bohemian: you're right. I started with "go read the javadoc", and then decided to be friendlier :-) Done now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**valueOf**

Returns Enum Constant by passing String specified enum type with the specified name.

**name**

name of enum constant as declared in its enum declaration.
You may use *toString()* method in preference to this method.

As I came to Know this:

*This name() method is designed primarily for use in situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release.*

While values returns *array* of all enum constants which is an *implicit* method.

Answer (score 6):

Read their javadoc ([Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html), for example, inheriting [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html), like all the enums), and you'll see what they're for.

`name()` is an instance method which returns the name of the instance.

`valueOf()` is a static method taking a String and returning the enum instance with that name.

`values()` is a static method returning all the enum instances.